# Oracle Query SQL Tuning?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select round(avg(et_gsm_sınyal)) as sinyal,mahalle_kodu,ilce_kodu,sebeke 
from 
    (select et_gsm_sınyal,sozlesme_no,SUBSTR(et_operator,1,5) as sebeke 
    from thkol316old 
    where tarih >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) 
    AND tarih < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')) okuma, 
    (select sozlesme_no,ilce_kodu,mahalle_kodu from commt020) bilgiler 
where okuma.sozlesme_no=bilgiler.sozlesme_no  
group by mahalle_kodu,ilce_kodu,sebeke;
```

- commt020 -> customer table
- thkol316old -> old bill table

This query is works but it's works very slow.

It's about 550 seconds response time.

What am I supposed to do this query work faster ?

It's the execution plan

```
SELECT STATEMENT 7547          

 HASH 
     GROUP BY    7547          

 FILTER 


 Filter Predicates 

 ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm'),-1)

 NESTED LOOPS 


 NESTED LOOPS 
         7546          

 TABLE ACCESS 
 COMMT020    BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID   3   ROW LOCATION    ROW LOCATION`
```

Comment: Answer no.1: Check execution plan. Then act accordingly... (To get execution plan, hit F10 in SQL developer, as you mentioned using that)

Comment: I tried but I don't understand what am i supposed to do ? Cost is 7547

Comment: Not the overall cost is important, but how the sub costs add up. You could also paste the text output here... Also, you can check the tree, tha part that is high cost, means the slowness is there...

Comment: @ppeterka - Cost does not equal slowness.  Cost is just Oracle's guess of relatively how expensive an operation is going to be.  If the optimizer were perfect, it would relate this way, but we all know this is not the case.. much better to use DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR with statistics_level = ALL (or gather_plan_statistics hint) to see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would try with ordinary table joins instead of the more awkward inline view - joining, I hope the following will work (I haven't created tables and tried it):

```
select round(avg(okuma.et_gsm_sınyal)) as sinyal,
bilgiler.mahalle_kodu,bilgiler.ilce_kodu, SUBSTR(okuma.et_operator,1,5) as sebeke 
from thkol316old okuma
inner join commt020 bilgiler on okuma.sozlesme_no=bilgiler.sozlesme_no
where okuma.tarih >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) 
AND okuma.tarih < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
group by bilgiler.mahalle_kodu,bilgiler.ilce_kodu, SUBSTR(okuma.et_operator,1,5);
```

Then, if things still are slow:

1. Verify that there is an index where bilgiler.sozlesme_no is the
   first column in the index
2. Verify that there is an index where okuma.sozlesme_no is the first column in the index
3. Verify that there is an index where okuma.tarih is the first column in the index

Answer (score 0):

Clearly

column tarih is not indexed for table thkol316old

`create index tarih_idx on thkol316old (tarih);`

Then

`analyze table commt020 compute statistics;`
`analyze table thkol316old compute statistics;`

In Oracle analyzing tables produce information that is used in creating query execution plans. Every time you alter a table you may want to also analyze it. Many big systems do it on a schedule.

Comment: analyze table is deprecated for statistics collection. Use DBMS_Stats instead.

Comment: Probably correct in this situation judging by the nature of the table involved, but be careful jumping straight to adding an index with no information on how selective the predicate filter is and how the data is actually laid out in the table.  Again, this probably fits for this example, but OP should be aware that trying to solve performance problems by just adding more indexes without investigating how much they will help is a terrible habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don’t need BILIGILER inline view just to select a few columns from COMMT020 table, you’ll be perfectly fine selecting from that table directly:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(et_gsm_s1nyal)) AS sinyal,
      mahalle_kodu,ilce_kodu,sebeke
FROM (
    SELECT et_gsm_s1nyal,
          sozlesme_no,
          SUBSTR(et_operator,1,5) AS sebeke
    FROM thkol316old
    WHERE tarih >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
    AND   tarih < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
    ) okuma, commt020    
WHERE okuma.sozlesme_no = commt020.sozlesme_no
GROUP BY mahalle_kodu,ilce_kodu,sebeke
/
```

Then, let’s rewrite the join using ANSI join expression. I prefer ANSI joins over old Oracle-style joins because they allow separating join conditions from filtering conditions, therefore providing more clarity into what’s actually going on. Also, it is a good style to assign aliases to the tables and clearly indicate which columns we select from which table.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(o.et_gsm_s1nyal)) AS sinyal,
      c.mahalle_kodu, c.ilce_kodu, o.sebeke
FROM (
    SELECT th.et_gsm_s1nyal,
          th.sozlesme_no,
          SUBSTR(th.et_operator,1,5) AS sebeke
    FROM thkol316old th
    WHERE th.tarih >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
    AND   th.tarih < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
    ) okuma o
JOIN  commt020 c ON o.sozlesme_no = c.sozlesme_no   
GROUP BY c.mahalle_kodu, c.ilce_kodu, o.sebeke
/
```

Now it is clearer than the remaining inline view is redundant too. Although it's hard to tell without knowing the details of those tables, but you will probably be better off “unwrapping” that inline view and replacing it with a straight join:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(th.et_gsm_s1nyal)) AS sinyal,
       c.mahalle_kodu,
       c.ilce_kodu,
       SUBSTR(th.et_operator,1,5) AS sebeke
FROM  commt020 c
JOIN  thkol316old th ON c.sozlesme_no = th.sozlesme_no
WHERE th.tarih >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
AND   th.tarih < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
GROUP BY c.mahalle_kodu, c.ilce_kodu, SUBSTR(th.et_operator,1,5)
/
```

Unfortunately optimizing this query further requires additional information, such as:

- The new execution plan.
- The version of Oracle you’re using.
- Numbers of rows in THKOL316OLD and COMMT020 tables.
- What indexes exist on those tables.